# how do I set variables and then add them

Tags: java, math

i want to define a variable to a button then when i press enter i want them to add like a calculator but the first 2 number dont get added they will be put side by side such as 2 and 7 would be 27 the multiply by the multiplier[I want it to have a variable set based on the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae6T8.png) then multiply them by multiplier

Comment: post the code no the screenshot

Comment: Your question is too broad.  No one can even use the code screenshot you included.  Please update your question and make it more specific.

Comment: Hey Ben, please check [ask]

Comment: i just want an answer, i feel like this is the only website that can help me and its tough to use :( looks like this project isn't gonna get finished

Comment: i cant post code as it says error with formatting

Comment: I suspect you are contcatening strings. `"1" + "2"` is `"12"`. whereas `1 + 2` is `3`. Try converting with `Integer.valueOf("1")` and add that

Comment: @vikingsteve which is strange since OPs want a multiplication but is using an addition sign, which is a concatenation operator with `String`

Comment: For me, you are clearly not reading to design a GUI that complex if you can't make the difference between an addition and an concatenation, or the difference between a number and a `String`. Learn the basis of JAVA langage first, it will be much easier for you to debug this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within you `ActionListener` define what you want to happen like "add 1" or multiply by "10"

Here is a very simplified form of your calculator (just for demonstration how you can implement such a thing) :

```
package com.example.resistorcalculator;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 */
public class ResistorCalculatorApplication {

    JFrame mainWindow;

    private double sum = 0.0;



    public static void main(String ...args) {
        new ResistorCalculatorApplication().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        mainWindow = build();
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }


    private class CalculatorSetValueActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private final double value; 

        public CalculatorSetValueActionListener(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sum = this.value;
            System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
        }

    }



    private class CalculatorAddValueActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private final double value; 

        public CalculatorAddValueActionListener(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sum += this.value;
            System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
        }

    }

    private class CalculatorMultipierValueActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private final double value; 

        public CalculatorMultipierValueActionListener(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            sum *= this.value;
            System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
        }

    }


    private JFrame build() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Example");
        Container contentPane = window.getContentPane(); 


        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
        JButton b11 = new JButton("Black - 0");
        b11.addActionListener(new CalculatorSetValueActionListener(0.0));

        contentPane.add(b11);

        JButton b12 = new JButton("Black - 0");
        b12.addActionListener(new CalculatorAddValueActionListener(0.0));

        contentPane.add(b12);


        JButton b13 = new JButton("Black - 0");
        b13.addActionListener(new CalculatorMultipierValueActionListener(1.0));

        contentPane.add(b13);




        JButton b21 = new JButton("Brown - 1");
        b21.addActionListener(new CalculatorSetValueActionListener(10.0));

        contentPane.add(b21);


        JButton b22 = new JButton("Brown - 1");
        b22.addActionListener(new CalculatorAddValueActionListener(1.0));

        contentPane.add(b22);


        JButton b23 = new JButton("Brown - 1");
        b23.addActionListener(new CalculatorMultipierValueActionListener(10.0));

        contentPane.add(b23);


        return window;

    }

}
```

It stores the total / sum displayed value in the `sum` field.
It has three kinds of `ActionListeners` one that replaces the value of the `sum` field by the value assigned to the action listener, one that adds the value of the `ActionLister` to the existing `sum` and one that multiplies the `sum` by the value stored in the action listener.

The value of the `sum` field is printed to the console when a button get's pressed.

Answer (score 1):

In resistor color code calculation the third band multiplier denotes the number of zeros to be appended at the end of the previous two bands. so in your scenario, you would append the values. so make the third band values as zeros instead of number. `example yellow,violet,red = 472 so 2 = '00', therefore = 4700ohm`

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to add some "value" to the buttons you can use `button.setName(value)` then you can get the value by using `button.getName()`. This keeps the button's text as you have set, and you will have a reference to its value. If you want to add them as you would add them in a calculator, you can use

`int sum = Integer.valueOf(button1.getName()) + Integer.valueOf(button2.getName())`

otherwise if you want to use like 2+7 = 27 you can simply add them as Strings(like `String sum = button1.getName() + button2.getName()`), then converting the concatenated String to integer by using `Integer.valueOf()`.

Comment: That does not work. You may parse the button name but than you still have do differentiate between adding and multiplying.